# Additional characters being added by replace method while reading and writing files in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file named **data.txt** and I am trying to replace multiple strings in that text file and output the edited version in another text file named **out.txt**. The problem is that instead of replacing it with correct strings that I mentioned in the code, it's adding random characters as well. Need Help with it. The text should be replaced by the numbers declared in the code, instead it adds some characters as well.

**This is the content of the data.txt file:**

```
[mks_progressbar name="Quality" level="qual_level/10" value="swpquality_level" height="20" color="#e23a3e" style="rounded"]

[mks_progressbar name="Features" level="feature_level/10" value="swpfeature_level" height="20" color="#f7c24e" style="squared"]

[mks_progressbar name="Easy To Use" level="easy_to_use_level/10" value="swpeasy_to_use_level" height="20" color="#2c9cb1" style="squared"]

[mks_progressbar name="Price" level="Price_level/10" value="swpPrice_level" height="20" color="#ab64bc" style="squared"]

[mks_progressbar name="Bonus" level="bonus_level/10" value="swpbonus_level" height="20" color="#dd9933" style="squared"]
```

**And this is my short code in Python**

```
# Declaring 5 variables
    quality_level_string=str(95)
    feature_level_string=str(100)
    easy_to_use_level_string=str(20)
    Price_level_string=str(40)
    bonus_level_string=str(60)

    fin = open("data.txt", "rt")  # To open my data.txt file

    fout = open("out.txt", "wt")  # To output in out.txt file after string replacement

    for line in fin:

# Using replace method to replace multiple string
    fout.write(line.replace("swpquality_level", quality_level_string).replace("swpfeature_level", feature_level_string).replace("swpeasy_to_use_level", easy_to_use_level_string).replace("swpPrice_level", Price_level_string).replace("swpbonus_level", bonus_level_string))


    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

**The Output I am getting in out.txt file is:**

```
[mks_progressbar name="Quality" level="9/10" value="90" height="20" color="#e23a3e" style="rounded"]

[mks_progressbar name="Features" level="10/10" value="swp10" height="20" color="#f7c24e" style="squared"]

[mks_progressbar name="Easy To Use" level="9.6/10" value="swp9.6" height="20" color="#2c9cb1" style="squared"]

[mks_progressbar name="Price" level="2.3/10" value="swp2.3" height="20" color="#ab64bc" style="squared"]

[mks_progressbar name="Bonus" level="2/10" value="swp2" height="20" color="#dd9933" style="squared"]
```

**The Correct Output should have been:**

```
[mks_progressbar name="Quality" level="9/10" value="95" height="20" color="#e23a3e" style="rounded"]

[mks_progressbar name="Features" level="10/10" value="100" height="20" color="#f7c24e" style="squared"]

[mks_progressbar name="Easy To Use" level="9.6/10" value="20" height="20" color="#2c9cb1" Style="squared"]

[mks_progressbar name="Price" level="2.3/10" value="40" height="20" color="#ab64bc" style="squared"]

[mks_progressbar name="Bonus" level="2/10" value="60" height="20" color="#dd9933" style="squared"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the code you are showing. At some point previous to this you replace `feature_level` with `10` as well as the other variable in the level field to handle `level="feature_level/10"`. The problem is that replacing `feature_level` in level will also replace it in value. It doesn't replace the "swp" though, because that's not part of the string you are replacing. That's also why the value is wrong.

To fix this swap the order in which you replace the level and value fields. That way replacing `feature_level` wont find any occurrences that you didn't mean it to.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean. I have made the changes and it fixed the problem. It was a tricky one for me as I am a newbie. Thank you so much for your help.